# @html.dropdownfor is not seleting default value

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, html.dropdownlistfor

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedProperty, Model.Property, "Please Select")
```

I have the above code in asp.net mvc3 to populate a dropdown list. Data populates but the selected item is the first item of the model result. I am trying to set default selected value as "Please select". How to do that?

Answer (score 2):

In your controller action you should set the value of the `SelectedProperty` to the value of the item you want to preselect:

```
model.SelectedProperty = "5";
```

This obviously assumes that the `Porperty` contains such a value:

```
model.Property = new[]
{
    new SelectListItem { Value = "1", Text = "item 1" },
    new SelectListItem { Value = "2", Text = "item 2" },
    new SelectListItem { Value = "3", Text = "item 3" },
    new SelectListItem { Value = "4", Text = "item 4" },
    new SelectListItem { Value = "5", Text = "item 5" },
    new SelectListItem { Value = "6", Text = "item 6" },
};
```

By setting `model.SelectedProperty = "5";`, the item with `Value="5"` will automatically be preselected by the `Html.DropDownListFor` helper.

If on the other hand you want to have the `"Please Select"` default value being shown, make sure in your controller action that the `SelectedProperty` is set to `null` and not to some value contained in the items.